# What does Digital Monitoring option do in Nero Wave Editor?

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording

I am using Nero Wave Editor 15.0 app to record audio at Line-In port of my Sound card on Windows 7. This software has an option to enable 'Digital Monitoring' in its recording settings.

I would like to know what does this option of Digital Monitoring do when enabled. Could not find much information on the internet or even in the Nero Manual.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found here](http://www.nero.com/eng/show-tutorial.php?tut=NTg)

> If you want to hear how the sound quality is modified by changing the
>   recording volume, then activate the Digital monitoring check box.

Comment: If I understand this correctly it’ll output what’s going to be recorded on your speakers (or headphones or whatever).

Comment: Thank you Snailking & Daniel B for the clarification. Yes that's right I now realize that with this option ON the processed output is redirected to default playback device, usually the speakers. I somehow did not notice it earlier because the checkbox on 'Listen to this device' option in recording device properties was already ON.